# Android Studio 3 not marking deprecated methods anymore

Tags: android, android-studio, deprecated, android-studio-3.0, deprecation-warning

I've noticed after the update to Android Studio 3 (but it could be happened also before and I didn't noticed) that **some** deprecated methods are not marked any more with a line-through. For example:

[image: Code screenshot]

I'm on Ubuntu, Android Studio 3.0.1 just updated. I checked inspections in the settings, and it's all enabled. I also checked that the code style/formatting is correctly set-up for deprecations (but it had to be, given the last line of the example is correctly marked). It's not something project-related, since I tried on a freshly created project.

What can cause this?

Comment: Have you tried "Restore defaults" for the inpections? It could be you're overlooking something.

Comment: update android studio to 3.0.1

Comment: @M0CH1R0N Yes, I tried, no change

Comment: @PranavAshok I'm already on 3.0.1, as I wrote in the question

Comment: Have you found a solution? I faced with this a few days ago. But I didn't update Android Studio, just restarted and some methods were not displayed as deprecated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally discovered that this is (strangely) the intended behaviour: https://issuetracker.google.com/65793314

> What's your minSdkVersion? It's a feature that we now only show deprecated method calls as deprecated if they're deprecated for all the versions you're trying to target

So, `getColor()` and `isAnimationCacheEnabled()` are not marked in my example because I'm targeting API 15+, and instead they're deprecated as of API 23. I confirmed this raising my app's minSdkVersion to 23, and they are all marked now.

Anyway I find this behaviour confusing and unnecessary, like I said in the bug report. If someone read this and agrees, please leave a comment [there](https://issuetracker.google.com/65793314).

Comment: This is still an issue in Android studio 4.1. Pretty annoying, if you ask me. Gradle build (Lint) reports something as deprecated (even though I use SDK_INT check there...), but AS doesn't tell me it's deprecated.... futhermore, when I use @SuppressWarning("deprecated") (to get rid of deprecation warning during build, which it does), AS tells me this suppresion is redundant... This is really inconsistent behavior. Not to mention Lint (during Gradle build) doesn't tell me on which API level something got deprecated... so I have to Google it myself for correct  SDK_INT check... Ugh...

Comment: So disappointed, IDE still don’t recognize deprecated or removed method that actual android api version changes. I must refactoring code, decrease api version and check for api changes 

Comment: @awa993, just set @SuppressWarnings({"deprecation", "RedundantSuppression"}) to avoid message "Suppresion is redundant"